# Lexicographically minimum string rotation

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Can someone explain me what does it mean to be a lexicographically minimal string. Here is an example from stack exchange

> Consider a string of length n (1 <= n <= 100000). Determine its
>   minimum lexicographic rotation. For example, the rotations of the
>   string “alabala” are:
>
> alabala
>
> labalaa
>
> abalaal
>
> balaala
>
> alaalab
>
> laalaba
>
> aalabal
>
> and the smallest among them is “aalabal”.

So this says smallest is "aalabal", is it because "aa" occurs twice at start? I am not able to interpret what makes "aalabal" the smallest? Can someone provide some insight?

Comment: Google and Wikipedia are your friends: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: Yup, the language of explanation sometimes gets the best of me. However, I get it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the question 'is what makes "aalabal" the smallest?', the answer is inevitably: '[lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)'.

Comment: I get it! The language used in describing the question I read, made me think otherwise. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**: Sorry, I just re-read your question and it seems you are stucked in the lexicographic part. Anyway, follow some links that other users provided and then check this later.

There is a well known way to solve this problem using [Suffix Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) (SA). Lets your string be `S`, then you concatenate `S` with itself and then apply SA. The output from SA is an array with the positions of every suffix sorted alphabetically. You can iterate and look for the first suffix that starts in any position in the range `[0, |S|)`. You need to think a bit about why this works, but at the end you can figure out easily.

For instance, lets `S = alabala`. You can see the SA output for `alabalaalabala` in the image below:

[image: Suffix Array for string alabalaalabala$]

The first suffix with position in the range `[0, |S|) = [0, 7)` is `SA[i] = 6` that correspond to the suffix `aalabala`.

Sometimes is convenient to add an special character at the end of the string before apply SA (implementation detail).

You can check a short implementation for SA below that runs in O(Nlg^2N), there are faster implementations but the idea behind this SA is the simplest one I guess.

1. Compile it (`g++ sa.cpp`)
2. Run it
3. Use as input the following values: `N = 15, S = alabalaalabala$`.
4. And check the output.

**Source Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int
      MaxN = 200005;

int N;
int i, k;
char s[MaxN];
int ord[MaxN];
int pos[MaxN];
int buc[MaxN];

bool cmp(const int& a, const int& b) {
    if (pos[a] != pos[b])
        return pos[a] < pos[b];
    if (a + k < N && b + k < N)
        return pos[a + k] < pos[b + k];
    return a > b;
}

int main() {

    cin >> N;
    cin >> s;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        ord[i] = i;
        pos[i] = s[i];
    }

    for (k = 0; k < N; k = k ? 2 * k : 1) {
        sort(ord, ord + N, cmp);
        for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
            buc[i] = buc[i-1] + cmp(ord[i-1], ord[i]);
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            pos[ord[i]] = buc[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << ord[i] << " - " << (s + ord[i]) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```